# unable to hide tmux-xpanes windows title

Tags: tmux

I used `set -g set-titles off` in .tmux.conf but it's not working.

screenshot:

```
xpanes -t -c "ping {}" 192.168.0.{1..9}
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Do you want allow-rename rather than set-titles? https://man.openbsd.org/tmux.1#set-titles https://man.openbsd.org/tmux.1#allow-rename

Comment: no...I want to hide the title showing in the screenshot.

Comment: You mean pane-border-format?

Comment: Yes. Parent pane border format.